# Image not showing in v-navigation-drawer background in Vue.js/Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am currently working on a project using Vue.js and Vuetify, and I am facing an issue with the v-navigation-drawer component when trying to set a local image as the background.

Here is the code that does not work:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    width="256"
    permanent
    image="@/assets/bg-2.jpg"
>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

However, when I use an external image URL, it works fine:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    width="256"
    permanent
    image="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/backgrounds/bg-2.jpg"
>
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

I have verified that the local image is in the assets folder. Any insights into why the local image is not being displayed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Move image over to the public folder.